# Python run command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a command line script.
I have :
command.py

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('python3 hello.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tmp = proc.stdout.read()
print(tmp)
```

and hello.py

```
print("hello")
```

but it returns error

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

How can I run command and print result?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Popen` cannot find `python3` in your path.

If the primary error was that `hello.py` wasn't found, you would have this error instead in `stderr` (that is not read)

```
python: can't open file 'hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

You would not get an exception in `subprocess` because `python3` has run but failed to find the python file to execute.

First, if you want to run a python file, it's better to avoid running it in another process.

But, if you still want to do that, it is better to run it with an argument list like this so spaces are handled properly and provide full path to all files.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen([r'c:\some_dir\python3',r'd:\full_path_to\hello.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tmp = proc.stdout.read()
print(tmp)
```

To go further:

- For `python3`, it would be good to put it in the system path to avoid specifying the full path.
- as for the script, if it is located, say, in the same directory and the current script, you could avoid to hardcode the path

improved snippet:

```
import subprocess,os
basedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3',os.path.join(basedir,'hello.py')], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tmp = proc.stdout.read()
print(tmp)
```

Also: `Popen` performs a kind of `execvp` of the first argument passed. If the first argument passed is, say, a `.bat` file, you need to add the `cmd /c` prefix or `shell=True` to tell `Popen` to create process in a shell instead that executing it directly.

Comment: ok, its work for my, BUT
why when i run
proc = subprocess.Popen(['casperjs',os.path.join(basedir,'casper_script.js')], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) its return error

Comment: capserjs is install